# It is possible to run scripts with elevated rights while screen is blocked?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, scripting, admin

I've inserted a PowerShell script to run when user clicks on the `utilman` (Ease of access) button to perform some default troubleshootings. But I've experienced some errors cause my scripts are not running as full elevated users.

For example, I've created a script that deletes all user profiles from Windows (`win32_userprofile`), but it returns `COMException - Result Code 0x80070522` when I run it with a locked screen, even when I pass admin credentials with `Get-Credential` method, it returns that error. But when I run that script with an unlocked screen, it works great!

[image: COM Exception]

[image: Result Code from Remove-WmiObject]

How can I run scripts with full admin rights while the screen is locked?

I've tried to run with external software that gives admin rights too (`elevate.exe`) which didn't work.

Comment: "A required privilege is not held by the client." are you sure you are elevated? How do you verify it?

Comment: Hello, Anders. When the powershell prompt is not elevated, a "Administrator" text appears on the left top. At least, i think that i'm elevated. Do you know any way that i can assure it?

Comment: Anders, i've found an answer to my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This command will let you run powershell as administrator

```
start-process PowerShell -verb runas
```

Replacing "Powershell" by another app will also grant the privileges, just add "" as in the example

```
start-process "notepad.exe" -verb runas
```

A prompt should appear asking you if you want to run it as administrator

Let me know if this works for you

Comment: Hello, Axanor. How are you?

I tried to do it but with no success :(

Any other ideas?

Comment: It looks like that even with Runas Argument my script can't access wmi objects

Comment: Hello Robert, add your user to the administator group/role it should help with running your script without depending on the change of permissions on execution

Comment: Also, I found this link, hope it helps on this issue
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/user-account-control-and-wmi

Comment: Hi, Axanor. How are you doing? My user already has admin permissions. But i'm going to check out the link that you sent. Thanks!

Comment: Axanor, i've found an answer to my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've found out a solution to my problem:

To pass user credentials, you can call **"Invoke-Command"** cmdlet. Like this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerName -Credential $credential -Scriptblock{Get-WmiObject Win32_UserProfile | ? LocalPath -notlike *anything* | Remove-WmiObject}
```

When i did that, everything worked great!

Thanks to Axanor and Anders help. Wish the best to you!